# Display "cookie consent banner" only to non-US visitors?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, cookies

Maybe this is an old question, but since 90% of my visitors are from USA I don't want to bug them with the annoying banner... how do I detect the country of origin? is it best using IP geolocation? or what else can be done? (js or php)

Thanks!

Comment: Regardning how: What have you tried? There are multiple, well documented, ways if you just search. Regarding what's best: I would think that it's either IP check in PHP or Geolocation in JS (but that requires the users consent). However, this won't work if the user is behind a proxy/VPN located in another country.

Comment: You can't rely 100% on it, however you choose to solve it. Anything coming from the client can be masked or altered. HTML5 offers a geolocation, but you may also use the ip-address. Or simply ask the user.

Comment: i'm trying to see if there is best/proved practice as there are way too many opinions about that out there...

Comment: What makes you think that you won't get as many different opinions here? :-) _"What's best"_ in this case is an opinion based question and also depends on the app.